# Get R Boxplot stats without drawing the boxplot

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, boxplot

I would like to generate the boxplot stats (whiskers, median) that I use to get the similarity between two vectors, but **without** generating the boxplot itself.

Let me better explain myself, through my code:

```
while(...){

doubleplot <- boxplot(real$dist, result$dist, names=c(paste("Loops (",length(real),")", sep=""),paste("Peak pairs (", length(result), ")",sep="")), ylab="Loop width", cex.lab=1.3, cex.axis=1.3, main="Candidate for negative loops", cex.main=1.5)
correl <- cor(doubleplot$stats[,1],doubleplot$stats[,2])

if(correl>max_correl){
    max_correl <- correl
    best_plot_data <- doubleplot
}

}
```

So obviously since we generate the boxplot stats in a while loop (100+ plots sometimes) it is very ressource intensive to actually draw the plots. I need the stats without the plot itself. Some sort of `boxplot(..., hidden=TRUE)`

Comment: The answer provided by Tomas will work.. You can calculate the correlation before hand to know which plot to make..

Comment: `boxplot(..., plot = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `boxplot.stats()`. It returns a list where one of the elements is `$stats` and you can access what you want there.

For example

```r
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(100)

boxplot.stats(x)

# $stats
# [1] -2.3456977 -0.9006166 -0.3846280  0.4828227  2.5489911

# $n
# [1] 100

# $conf
# [1] -0.6032114 -0.1660445

# $out
# numeric(0)
```

For more info you can look at `?boxplot.stats()`